# RCP - Environmental Variables for the product.ini file?

Tags: java, windows, rcp

I need a way to use relative paths in my product.ini file for our RCP application. It usually looks something like this (the variables are edited and do not work)

> -startup %COMMONPROGRAMFILES(x86)%/PRODUCT/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
>
> --launcher.library %COMMONPROGRAMFILES(x86)%/PRODUCT/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
>
> -vm jre1845_copy/bin

Apparently it works for https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=241192 the config.ini ... can I make it work for product.ini as well?